# How much RAM does my program use to allocate a message for sending POST over HTTPS?

Tags: c++, memory-management, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm sending my POST request over HTTPS like that:

```
const char* fingerprint = "5D DS 5F 3D 2A 4C H8 31 AE 3F E4 21 C3 04 F3 3E C2 A2 43 05";
String postStr = "temperature=";
postStr += String(average_dht_temp);
postStr += "&humidity=";
postStr += String(average_humidity);
postStr += "&pressure=";
postStr += String(average_pressure);
http.begin("https://example.com/endpoint", fingerprint);
http.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZnNkZnNmc2Rmc2Rmc2Q6cnczNXJmc2ZzcjMyZnM=");
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
int statusCode = http.POST(postStr);
http.end();
```

And lately a person who is implementing the same request in his system asked me how much memory in RAM do I allocate for this message. And since I'm a beginner in C++ I'm not sure what is the right answer to that question?

**The code is for ESP8266 (Arduino).**

Comment: Why don't you use a profiler to find out? BTW why so many concatenations? You generate quite a few strings

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because .. check the tags. It *is* a small embedded system with very limited memory. One would care on any system though, as wasted allocations and CPU mean for example that you end up serving *fewer* requests per web server.

Comment: I'm on ESP8266 and the person in question is trying to do the same request on some ARM. I'm not sure what a profiler is in context of that? What I know of, is that I can call ESP.getfreeheap() but not sure in what point?

Comment: you should specify this on the question itself, not just the tags. Arduino uses a language that isn't quite C++. In C++ one would use a string stream and stream operators.